# Positive rotational symmetric solution for p-Laplacian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I have the the following problem and I just can't get my head around how to solve it.
Be $1<p<n$ and $q=\frac{np}{n-p}$, $u\in\mathcal{C}_{n,p}=\{f\in W^{1,p}_{loc}: \|f\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)}=1\}$ and

$
\mathcal{F}(u)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|Du|^p.
$

Find all positive, rotational symmetric solutions for the corresponding Euler-Lagrange-Equation.

I don't need a perfect solution just some ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: I suggest you write out the Euler-Lagrange equation (which is the p-Laplace equation), and then write the equation in spherical coordinates. Rotationally symmetric solutions mean that the function is of $r$ alone, which should give you an ODE.